# Javascript/J-Query dynamically resizing grid squares

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, grid-layout

what I'm asking about may be a bit too specific to be realistic, but what I'm looking for is a way to have a table/grid in a webpage that is composed of colour-coded cells. Upon clicking a cell, it expands to reveal the previously hidden contents of the cell. Ideally this would be accompanied by some sort of jquery-esque smooth animation.

I'm not asking necessarily for a complete solution here, but rather where I would need to start looking in order to be able to create something along these lines.

What I'm thinking is something that looks like this before you click on a cell:
[image: before click]

And this afterwards:
[image: after click]

Thanks in advance,

Kez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips, guys, I actually managed to get pretty much exactly what I wanted using your advice. In particular the event.target property came in useful. Thanks, Izzluca.

I have created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fw8rsd9f/) showing my solution.

I gave a class ("tlight") to every cell I wanted to be able to resize, and used the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tlight').bind('click', resizeAll);

        function resizeAll() {
            $('.tlight').animate({
                height: 50,
                width: 50
            }, "slow");
            $(event.target).animate({
                height: 100,
                width: 100
            }, "slow");
        };
    });
```

- Kez

Answer (score 0):

**Use Javascript**

Try this

```
<td id="name1" onclick="myfunction()"><div id="content"></div></td>
```

Java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction()
       {
        $("#content").html("Cell Content Become Visible "); 
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am getting the problem...

It looks like you have to add a listener for the click event, on every td or maybe, ligther, on the tbody of the table: checking the "event.target" property you could be able to get to the td that raised the event (I am assuming you are working with an HTML table).

For the content, you could store it directly inside the cell itself, maybe inside a div wrapper; you can set the css property overflow on the wrapper, showing the content as much as you want (you should have to specify the height/width of the wrapper and "overflow:hidden;" on it, if I recall correctly). The cell will resize accordingly with its content.

At the click handler, you can change the overflow property to "overflow:visible;": in that case, all the content will be shown (or just change the height/width to show more of it).
If you don't set any fixed height for the table's cells, the row will get the height of the highest cell, so you don't have to fix the row's height when you explode the cell's content.

PS: Maybe interesting: using "table-layout:fixed;" you should be able to assign a percentage height to the rows, like:

```
table {
  height: 300px; 
}

.row1: {
  height: 50%;
}

.row2: {
  height: 50%;
}
```